# How to create list in view (SQL) using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql, .net-core, view, entity-framework-core

I have this code:

```
public class Anh  
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Name { get; set; }
   public List<Em> Ems { get; set; }
}

public class Em 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Name { get; set; }
   public int IdAnh { get; set; }
   public Anh Anh { get; set; }
}
```

I created a view in SQL. It is return data like this:

| Id | Name | IdEm | NameEm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 | Cari |
| 1 | John | 3 | Mimi |

But I failed, when I want to create a List Em in class Anh:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Anh>(eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
            eb.ToView("View_AnhEm");
            eb.Property(v => v.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            eb.Property(v => v.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
            eb.HasOne(x => x.Anh).WithMany(x =>x.Ems).HasForeignKey(x => x.IdAnh);
           
        })
```

Unless I combine the attributes of class Anh and class Em the same class. But ANH is while it may have more EM. And EM has only one ANH.

```
public class AnhEm  
{
   public int IdAnh { get; set; }
   public int NameEm { get; set; }
   public int IdEM { get; set; }
   public int NameEm { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why you are mapping Anh class to View_AnhEm view? To maitain a list you should define a relationship. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: I know it. My data comes in 4 tables. So don't make mistakes about the relationship. I need to create a class in class B that is the list of A. And it gets the result returned from the View